# How can I rerun a method until it succeeds?

Tags: java, thread-safety, wait, sleep

I want to rerun a method until it succeeds. I would like to block the application until it succeeds.

I'm currently using this code

```
public synchronized void initApplicationWithRetry() throws InterruptedException {
    int retriesCounter = 0;
    while (!isJobDone && retriesCounter < 3) {
        try {
            doJob();
        } catch (DummyException e) {
            //handle error
        } finally {
            ++retriesCounter; // For some reason it's not incremented
        }
        if (isJobDone) {
            return;
        }
        wait(3000); //waits for 3 second
    }
    if (!isJobDone) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

My issue is `retriesCounter` doesn't seem to get incremented. Which is one of the termination conditions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You to initialize `isJobDone` to false, and change it to `true` if the job succeeds. Also you need to initialize `retriesCounter = 0` not `5`

```
public synchronized void initApplicationWithRetry() throws InterruptedException {
    boolean isJobDone = false;
    int retriesCounter = 0;
    while (!isJobDone && retriesCounter < 3) {
        try {
            doJob();
            isJobDone = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle error
        } finally {
            ++retriesCounter; // For some reason it's not incremented
        }
        if (!isJobDone) {
            wait(3000); //waits for 3 second
        }
    }
    if (!isJobDone) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my edit. `retriesCounter` was initialized to 5 by mistake. `isJobDone` is initialized to `false` out of the method. Still, the issue remains. Using the debugger I noticed it's not the counter is not incremented properly

Comment: if you add a print of retriesCounter  after the closing finally bracket you always see 0 ? And with a log inside the finally it doesn't show up ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what puzzles me

Comment: Added some logs, and the counter gets incremented but never reaches 3 which is the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use a loop, try with a TimerTask.

TimerTask repeats executing the "run" method every "waitTime" milliseconds. You can specify when to stop repeating this task by calling "timer.cancel()"

```
public void initApplicationWithRetry() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                doJob();
                timer.cancel(); // runs when there is no exception
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                // Handle error
            }
        }
    }
}, 0, waitTime);
```

**Note:** If you want to know how many retries has be done, just put a counter to the catch or finally block.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the RuntimeException is causing an issue with the loop termination condition.

When the RuntimeException is thrown, it is not caught by the catch block in the loop, and instead propagates up the call stack until it is caught by the nearest catch block that can handle it. If there is no such block, the program terminates with an error.

In this case, the RuntimeException is not caught by the loop, and so the loop continues to run indefinitely.